# Can't Run SFC Scannow (Windows 10, Dell XPS 8500)

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps, sfc

I have been having issues trying to update Windows.

Whenever I access anything related to the Windows update processes that program freezes up. I try to check updates from the settings menu and the entire settings menu freezes up. I ran the troubleshooter and it didn't find any problems.

I attempted to run `SFC/Scannow` to repair damage or corrupted files in the system related to the Windows update service and it manages to get to `8%` before it says:

***Windows resource protection could not perform the requested operation*** and stops.

I've tried to run the process in safe mode as well with the same result.

In order to try and repair SFC I ran DISM's `/RestoreHealth` command and it went to `100%` and `/CheckHealth` along with `/ScanHealth` report no problems related to the system image. However SFC still refuses to do anything past `8%`.

I have also attempted to do an in-place Windows upgrade but that resulted in it eventually checking for updates and hanging forever around 60% and never progressing anywhere.

What can I do to resolve this issue, short of reinstalling Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have also attempted to do an in-place windows upgrade but that
> resulted in it eventually checking for updates and hanging forever
> around 60% and never progressing anywhere

Try again a Windows 10 Repair Install.

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

If this fails to run properly, then you need to back everything up and re-install Windows.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I needed, after using the setup from the USB and selecting to not install updates at the time it fully completed. So far everything seems to be running smoothly again, thank you!

Comment: Thank you for the update.